# Open pdf file in Microsoft Word using OLE

Tags: pdf, ms-word, abap, ole

I am looking for the method (of Word ole-object) which can open pdf in the Microsoft Word.
I want to copy all pages of pdf into doc/docx and add there footers.
Could anybody give the cue how to import pdf?
PS: any sample code for this problem would be great.

Thanks,
Lilya

Comment: could you provide in your question  the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Answer (score 0):

You need OCR (Optical Character Recognition) engine for converting PDF to document. PDF is generic format and it can include text as image. So it is very hard to convert PDF to document. SAP hasn't got any OCR function for doing this. Maybe OpenText (if customer using it) has this functionality, I haven't got detail information about opentext. You need third party tools for this. You can use online services or command line utilities to converting PDF files to text files easelly if PDF included text, otherwise you need professional SDKs (for example Abbyy Finereader) for doing this.

Comment: I think it's possible to do that through methods of ole-object of Microsoft Word. By the way I opened pdf in Microsoft Word (newer versions than 2013 can do that). But I need to do that programmatically, haven't found solution yet.

Comment: I can't open PDF files on Mac with latest Word 16.16.3. Are you sure opening with Word instead of attaching PDF file to Word?

Comment: Yes, I opened all pages of pdf file in Microsoft Word 2013 (15.0.5067.1000)

Comment: You can try to [Excel example](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/Snippets/ABAP+-+OLE+Automation+using+MS-Excel) to convert Word. You can find [detail OLE here](https://archive.sap.com/kmuuid2/204d1bb8-489d-2910-d0b5-cdddb3227820/An%20Easy%20Reference%20for%20OLE%20Automation.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

I used FoxIT PDF Reader to save the PDF file into text file and make a macro to read the text file. Of course, by doing so, you can only get the text, but nothing else.